# JaxB representation for Object to support different types

Tags: jaxb

Following java property can be of either String/Integer type. I tried adding annotation as below, but it would only take the last type(string in this case), even when an integer is passed. How can we allow multiple types for this property?

```
@XmlElements({
@XmlElement(type = Integer.class), @XmlElement(type = String.class)
})
private Object val1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no name to differentiate between the different type of classes when unmarshaling. I don't know what exactly are your requirements but this is how you could make it work:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeRoot {
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name="string", type = String .class),
            @XmlElement(name="int", type = Integer.class)
    })
    private Object val;

    public SomeRoot(Object val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public SomeRoot() { }
}
```

When you have a String value provided it would be marshaled into something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <string>test</string>
</root>
```

And when given an Integer it would marshal into something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <int>1</int>
</root>
```

Both of these would be unmarshaled to their proper type because of the difference in the element name.

Also if you would have a list of Objects you could marshal/unmarshal something like this with no problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <int>1</int>
    <string>test1</string>
    <string>test2</string>
    <string>test3</string>
    <int>3</int>
</root>
```

Update:

If you want both types under the `<val>` element, you could use a custom XmlAdapter to check on the type. This could look like this:

```
public class MyXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Object> {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public MyXmlAdapter() {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO - Handle Exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Element element = (Element) v;
        String elementValue = element.getTextContent();
        if(StringUtils.isNumeric(elementValue)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(elementValue);
        } else {
            return new String(elementValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        return v; 
    }

}
```

And your root class would be something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeRoot {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyXmlAdapter.class)
    private Object val;

    public SomeRoot(Object val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public SomeRoot() { }

    public Object getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Trying this out in a simple main, resolves the provided xml to the right type for both String and Integer on val:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeRoot.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdapter(new MyXmlAdapter());

            SomeRoot pojo = (SomeRoot) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(pojo.getVal().getClass());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @mart, however the issue is this value will be sent through one property only. Is it not possible for a single name to have multiple types        ? A sample xml content would be like below where <value> can have either string/int.  <root> <type>integer</type>
    <value>1</value>
</root>